# Multi-client web-cam access and stream processing from python server in real-time

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask, webrtc

I am in the process of making a web application that essentially takes in some web-stream from the client via their browser, and in real-time, sends it to a python server (Flask probably) that processes the frames in real-time and sends a response to the user. Now the backend has to be capable of handling web-streams from multiple clients simultaneously.

I am trying to grasp the framework for this entire application. What I have in mind is the following:

1. The user accesses the web-cam via their browser (e.g using webcamJS), the frames are sent from the frontend to the back-end through a web-socket. The task here is to establish a seemless handshake between the multiple clients and their processing requests.
2. There is a need for concurrency if the processing is to be done in real-time, multiple threads of the same image-processing-algorithm need to be executed. My take is that I make use of the multiple threads for this purpose or is there a better way of doing this? Is this even a feasible approach as the image-processing-algorithm (trained model) takes some time to load up , so it has to be always initialized at the backend and not start from scratch at every request.
3. The response from image-processing-algorithm need to get back to the frontend and the process goes on.

What I really need help is in drawing out the complete framework of this implementation. Any suggestions on the modules/frameworks to use with some implementations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) means that a multithreaded CPython process will still only be able to execute Python bytecodes on a single CPU at a time.  If all of the "real work" (video processing) is being done by calling out to a C or C++ library rather than in Python, that might be okay, but if you're doing anything computationally-intensive in Python, you're likely to find your server unable to take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The video-processing is performed using python libraries such as opencv and numpy, and keras is also used for prediction on those video frames after they are processed. Those are, external C/C++ libraries as far as I know. So theoretically, I could create 10 threads and send in 10 frames at a time rather than one-by-one and get 10x the speed?

Comment: I'd imagine so, as long as opencv/numpy are designed to support that.  (I haven't used them myself so I can't say).  Note that if there are inter-frame dependencies (e.g. the correct rendering of frame #2 depends on the results of how frame #1 was rendered) that might be an issue in parallelizing things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flask for your web server, Keras to process the videos.

The standard library `multiprocessing` module will also be helpful to treat multiple feeds at once.